# What is a "balanced-token-seq"

Tags: c++, c++11

I just read about the grammar of C++11 and I got this:

```
balanced-token-seq:
    balanced-token opt
    balanced-token-seq balanced-token

balanced-token:
    ( balanced-token-seq )
    [ balanced-token-seq ]
    { balanced-token-seq }
any token other than a parenthesis, a bracket, or a brace
```

I spent hours of time still cannot figure out the meaning of balanced-token-seq. I would be appreciate if somebody give me a help!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion

Comment: Hey Mike, what on earth are you doing? Stop vandalizing your posts, there's no point in doing that. What's bothering you with having them visible?

Comment: Not a good trick for getting points !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence of tokens with balanced brackets (i.e. a `[` will have a matching `]`, etc.).

```
[ ( a ) b { c } ] // a balanced token seq
[ { a x ( } ]     // not a balanced token seq
```